# How to append list to a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, append

I want to append a list to a list.

```
foo([a,b,c]).
goo([d,e,f]).
hi(X):-append(foo(X),goo(X)).
```

I want to get the result as shown below. But I realized I cannot execute `foo(X)` and `goo(X)`.

```
?- hi(X).
|: [a,b,c,d,e,f].
```

Comment: You can, but this is not the way to do it. Prolog has *no* functions, it only has *predicates*.

Answer (score 1):

A common misconception about Prolog is that it has *no* functions: it only has predicates. A predicate has no input or output, it unifies variables with which it is called. As a result, a predicate can be *mutlidirectional*.

Another misconception about prolog is that if you call:

```
append(foo(X), goo(Y)).
```

that Prolog will see `foo(x)` and `goo(Y)` as predicate calls. It does not: in this case `foo(X)` and `goo(Y)` are *terms*. Terms with a **functor** (not a predicate) and terms. So here `foo(X)` is a term with the functor `foo/1` with term `X` as first (and only) parameter.

You can however *call* predicates, by writing these in the *body* of another predicate.

Here for instance you probably want:

```
hi(X) :-
    foo(A),
    goo(B),
    append(A, B, X).
```

So how does this works? If we call `hi(X)`, then Prolog will look in the source code for whether there is a predicate defined by that name. If there is, it will aim to execute the *clauses* of the predicate top to bottom. Here there is only one clause for `hi/1`, the one we have just written. So now Prolog will start executing the *body* of that clause.

We now see that the first item in the body is `foo(A)` (notice the `A`, not `X`). SO now Prolog will again look for a clause for the `foo/1` predicate. And there is one in your question. `foo([a,b,c])`. That means that Prolog will now perform *unification*. It will *unify* our variable `A` with the fact. So after calling the `foo/1` predicate, now `A = [a,b,c]`. We do the same with `goo(B)`: after calling it, `B = [d,e,f]`.

Finally we call `append(A, B, X).`. Now `append/3` is a builtin predicate that appends the lists in the two first parameters to the third parameter (but it can be used multidirectional). After the call, `X` will thus be unified as `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`. Since it is the end of the predicate call, Prolog will report that `X = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

Are we done now? No! Another vital aspect of Prolog is that it has *backtracking syntactically for free*. That means that for each predicate call we have done (`foo(A)`, `goo(B)`, and `append(C)`), there can still be clauses in which we are interested. So conceptually the Prolog interpreter will look for more answers. But here we are lucky that `foo/1` and `goo/1` have only one definition. Note that most Prolog interpreters will not have to do this backtracking here, since they will do some bookkeeping such that it is known in advance whether we should try to backtrack.

Comment: *syntactical backtracking*? That notion does not exist.

Comment: @false: I borrowed it from a discussion with my PhD supervisor (Bart Demoen) once. It based on the fact that in Prolog, "you get backtracking" for free. Not in the computational sense, but in the syntactical sense. If I recall correctly the terms was introduced when Maurice Bruynooghe wanted to hire Bart Demoen for the Prolog research team at KU Leuven, although I might have forgotten the details.

Comment: There is *syntactic unification*. That is, theory-free or equipped with Herbrand-theory. There is *chronological backtracking*, however.

Comment: @false: what is meant, is that you do not have to write a program with structure to do the backtracing: it is done automatically from the moment you introduce a new clause. So it is free in the sense that it does not cost any effort to turn a straightforward program into one with backtracing. With "syntactically for free". I reordered it (probably one of the downsides of having lived in a country that has both Roman and German language families, is that adjectives are placed in illogical orders).

Comment: As it stands, it does not make any sense.

Comment: @false: then so be it. :) Like a person once said, logic brings you (hopefully) from A to B, imagination (and sometimes creativity) will take you everywhere.

Comment: Can you point to some publication by the aforementioned that uses this notion?

Comment: @false: I will try to find back the blogpost, but currently at work :)

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to write your own appending predicate, it might help you to more fully understand Prolog:

```
append_list([],L, L).
append_list([Head|Tail], List2, [Head|List]):-
     append_list(Tail, List2, List).
```

It takes the first element of your first list and plugs it into the resultant list, then recursively calls itself without the first element of the list meaning it will move onto the second element. The base predicate is `append_list([], L, L).` this says: when the first list is empty return the resultant list.

Plugging in your values

```
append_list([a,b,c],[d,e,f],X).
```

Will return `X = [a, b, c, d, e, f]`